# Where can I get a proper hot chocolate in Firenze-Venezia-Trieste?

Tags: food-and-drink, italy, venice, cafes, florence

I am right now in Firenze but will spend two days in Venice and two days in Trieste and I'd like to drink a proper, thick, tasty hot chocolate but everyone says they don't make it in the summer. Any ideas? In Firenze I have a one week bus pass so I'm not limited to any area.

Comment: I'd love to see the faces waiters make when you ask them for hot chocolate in the hot Italian summer. :)

Comment: Sorry I did not snap photos when I already asked at least a dozen cafes here. They serve hot tea, cafe -- why not chocolate?

Comment: Ernest Hemingway can be your friend.  At least in and around Trieste...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Hot Chocolate and the Italian Summer

As many, many waiters must have told you, hot chocolate is not exactly a summer drink. I do understand that those same establishments probably serve hot coffee and tea in the summer, however tea is somewhat of a more multi-season drink whereas coffee is a daily drink for most Italians.

In my opinion, if you wish to maximise the likelihood of finding hot chocolate, you should target specialised establishments, or **Cioccolaterie** (literally chocolate-places in Italian). Your search keywords should be something like `cioccolata calda XXX` or `cioccolateria XXX`, where `XXX` is the city you wish to search in.

#### Hot Chocolate in Firenze

Searching around on the internet for `cioccolata calda Firenze` yields many results (see [here](https://mangiaspaghy.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/la-migliore-cioccolata-calda-di-firenze/) and [here](http://www.teladoiofirenze.it/cibo/larte-del-cioccolato-a-firenze-e-i-suoi-5-luoghi/) for two sample reviews in Italian). The consensus however seems to point towards [Rivoire](https://www.google.fr/maps/place/Rivoire/@43.7701057,11.2555215,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x132a54005628c53d:0x82c4ea1b14564bfc) which is known for making their own chocolate, as well as serving thick hot chocolate beverages. Another option could be [Cioccolateria Hemingway](https://www.google.fr/maps/place/Hemingway/@43.7681651,11.2432825,16z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x132a5152cbc2d8b3:0xf6804800cc09c26d). None of these specify if they serve hot chocolate in the summer. Nevertheless it might be worth trying them since, being Cioccolaterie, they are definitely more likely to have hot chocolate on their menus.

Comment: I'm sitting in the Rivoire right now. Proper hot chocolate confirmed (although it's September and not July). I have a very faint memory of not good hot chocolate served at a fancy place last year. Might have been some miscommunication, might have been another place but right now I am in hot chocolate heaven.

Comment: @chx Glad to hear that. Enjoy it! :)

Answer (score 3):

There are quite some places to try in **Trieste**.
I suggest to try [Chocolat](http://www.tripadvisor.it/Restaurant_Review-g187813-d2718750-Reviews-Chocolat-Trieste_Province_of_Trieste_Friuli_Venezia_Giulia.html) first. From there you can walk towards [Piazza Unità](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piazza_Unit%C3%A0_d%27Italia) and check a local [Torrefazione](http://www.tripadvisor.it/Restaurant_Review-g187813-d5096786-Reviews-Torrefazione_La_Triestina-Trieste_Province_of_Trieste_Friuli_Venezia_Giulia.html) (they serve tea and coffee also). Behind Piazza Unità there's [Gelato Marco](http://www.tripadvisor.it/Restaurant_Review-g187813-d2653136-Reviews-Gelato_Marco-Trieste_Province_of_Trieste_Friuli_Venezia_Giulia.html), a *gelateria* (ice cream place) where they serve ice-cream covered in hot chocolate!
After visiting the old city centre, walk in *viale XX settembre* to try [Madison](http://www.tripadvisor.it/ShowUserReviews-g187813-d2035300-r97295559-Gelateria_Madison-Trieste_Province_of_Trieste_Friuli_Venezia_Giulia.html). This is a rather long pedestrian area filled with restaurants, bars, gelaterie. At late afternoon it gets crowded for *aperitivo*.

Everything I linked is in walking distance.

Answer (score 3):

I just learned of the existence of [VizioVIrtù](http://www.viziovirtu.com/shop/in-a-cup/) in Venice. Look at this:

[image]

And the text suggests it's served in every season:

> Each season has its chocolate drink. True, as this drink is exquisite also if served cold. Is your mouth watering? Try the milkless and sugarless one.